# Angular Multi tab with individual instance of components running with routing in individual tabs

Tags: angular, routes, tabs

I need solution to one of my problem, I need to create an application where new tabs will be added dynamically during runtime, and each tab must have its own instance of components running, I used direct component tag in each tab, But routing doesn't work, For that I used router-outlet in each tab, As a result the routing happens only on the latest added tab even if you click on the links on the first tab. Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Note: Named router outlet method doesn't support dynamic naming.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.